# to overcome type error?

Tags: python

i have a file of this format:

```
3.334 1
2.345 1
1.453 1
3.343 1
and so on
```

but in middle at times in file there are few number which are not in float format and i receive type msg when i run them performation some operation..

I want to give a condition that:

```
if(not in float format):
  continue
else:
  perform operation
```

please tell me how to put the condtion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an exception handler:

```
try:
    f = float(thing)
except ValueError:
    # This is not a float
    f = 0.0
```

`ValueError` is thrown by invalid conversions. You should have seen it in your application traceback when an invalid float value conversion was tried.